# Rolling dice with over 7 digits

Tags: c, random

My aim is to make a program that will throw two dice until the top faces of the two dice total to a number. 
However, in my code, i roll a dice with over 7 digits. Help me please, Thank you!

My code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int intRandom(int a=1,int b=6)
{
    int n;
    n=a+rand()%b;
    return n;

}

int main()
{
    int i,n,x,y; /*n:total, i:count*/
    printf("Dice Thrower\n================\n");
    printf("Total sought: ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
    } while (n<2 && n>12);

    {
        i=1;
        srand(time(NULL));
        do
        {
            x=intRandom(2,6);
            y=intRandom(6,2);

            printf("Result of throw %d: %d + %d\n",i,x,y);
            if ((x+y)==n) printf("\nYou got your total in %d throws!\n",i);

            fflush(stdin);

            i++;            
        } while ((x+y)!=n);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your objective, and what are the problems you are facing (errors, etc). Please edit your question to clarify that...

Comment: Why are you calling `intRandom` with anything other than the default argument values?

Comment: Changing the arguments as you have to your random call will make it fail.

Comment: `int i,n,x,y; /*n:total, i:count*/` -- If `n` is "total" and `i` is "count", just call them `total` and `count`. `fflush(stdin);` The standard doesn't define the behavior of `fflush` on input streams. What exactly do you expect that call to do?

Comment: You need to explain clearly how your program is failing. I can't tell what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, if you had looked at the output of your program, you should have saw that both dice were misbehaving, especially the 2nd, which gave a 6 - 7 only result, while the first only gives 2 - 7.  Because of this, your values could only fall within the region of 8 - 14 (hence your question).  Using the default parameters to your random function, as has been suggested, fixes this issue.

Comment: Tagged [C]. But `int intRandom(int a=1,int b=6)` - this is not C.

Comment: @AnT Excuce me, its C ;\

Comment: @Yasaka Magatama: No, it is not. This could be C++, but this is not even remotely C. `#include <ctime>` is not C. `int intRandom(int a=1,int b=6)` is not C.  `fflush(stdin);` is undefined in both C++ and C.

Answer (score 3):

Change the random number generation to

```
x=intRandom(1,6);
y=intRandom(1,6);
```

Comment: Better still, `x = intRandom()` etc.

Comment: Touche. Yes default arguments tend to trip up C compilers. (You might want to mention that in this answer.) Have an upvote.